# How can I make a grid fixed, not affected by scrolling?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The structure of the code I am working on is looking like this:

```
<Grid>
  <ListView>
     <ListView.Resources>
     </ListView.Resources>

     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Border>
             <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                </Grid>

                <ListView>
                </ListView>

                <Grid>
                <!-- List of the data can be long. So I want this grid to be fixed, not affected by scrolling, but there could be multiple lists as well. So when I scroll to the end of one list, the other one begins, then the grid of other list should appear, and stay fixed -->
                </Grid>
 
             <StackPanel> 
          </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <ListView> 
<Grid>
```

The red arrow tells where the grid is and how it should look like, currently the list is long with more than 100 items in it, and to get to this grid I have to scroll all the way down which is not good in practice...

[Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JowoC.png)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OwRS.png)

Comment: I need a picture of what you're expecting.

Comment: I have posted the picture in description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the header table in sync with the content table horizontally on scroll event. Use **table-layout: fixed** so that applied column width remains the same. One more thing adjust the header table by giving an extra td, at last, to get accurate width as same as content table after getting a scroll bar on content table